# How can I reduce this code to draw a cone and a pyramid

Tags: graphics3d

I am trying to draw [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/612373/how-to-draw-this-cone/612381#612381) by *Mathematica*. I tried

```
Clear[a, b, c, d];
d = {0, 0, 0};
b = {3, 0, 0};
c = {0, 3, 0};
a = {0, 0, 3};
g = (a + b + c)/3;
r = EuclideanDistance[g, a];
Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5], Cone[{g, d}, r], Black, 
  Text[Style["D", Italic, 14, FontFamily -> "Times"], {0, 0, -0.2}],
  Text[Style["A", Italic, 14, FontFamily -> "Times"], {0, 0, 3.1}],
  Text[Style["B", Italic, 14, FontFamily -> "Times"], {3.1, 0, 0}],
  Text[Style["C", Italic, 14, FontFamily -> "Times"], {0, 3.1, 0}],
  Text[Style["G", Italic, 14, FontFamily -> "Times"], {1, 1, 0.8}],
  Thick, Blue, Line[{{a, b, c, a}, {d, a, b, d}}],
  Dashed, Red, Line[{{d, g}, {d, c}}],
  Blue, {PointSize[0.015], Point[{a, b, c, d, g}]}}, Boxed -> False]
```

I got

[image]

And tried

```
Clear[a, b, c, d];
d = {0, 0, 0};
b = {3, 0, 0};
c = {0, 3, 0};
a = {0, 0, 3};
g = (a + b + c)/3;
r = EuclideanDistance[g, a];
\[ScriptCapitalR] = Tetrahedron[{a, b, c, d}];
Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5], Cone[{g, d}, r], Black,
  EdgeForm[{Blue}], FaceForm[{Pink, Opacity[0.2]}], \[ScriptCapitalR],
  Text[Style["D", Italic, 14, FontFamily -> "Times"], {0, 0, -0.2}],
  Text[Style["A", Italic, 14, FontFamily -> "Times"], {0, 0, 3.1}],
  Text[Style["B", Italic, 14, FontFamily -> "Times"], {3.1, 0, 0}],
  Text[Style["C", Italic, 14, FontFamily -> "Times"], {0, 3.2, 0}],
  Text[Style["G", Italic, 14, FontFamily -> "Times"], {1, 1, 0.8}],
  Black, {PointSize[0.015], Point[{a, b, c, d, g}]}
  }, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

How can I reduce those codes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
labels = Style[#, Italic, 14, FontFamily -> "Times"] & /@ {"A", "B", "C", "D", "G"}

coordinates = {a, b, c, d, g};

cone = Graphics3D[{Opacity @ .5, Cone[{g, d}, Norm[g - a]]}];
```

We can use [`MeshRegion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshRegion.html) and the options [`MeshCellStyle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshCellStyle.html) and [`MeshCellLabel`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshCellLabel.html) to style and label the primitives:

```
tetrahedron = MeshRegion[coordinates, 
  {Tetrahedron @ Range @ 4, Line[{{4, 5}, {4, 3}}]}, 
  MeshCellStyle -> {2 -> FaceForm[],
     0 -> Directive[PointSize[Large], Black],
     {1, _} -> Directive[Blue, Thick],
     {1, 5 | 7} -> Directive[Orange, Thick, Dashed]}, 
  MeshCellLabel -> Table[{0, i} -> labels[[i]], {i, 5}]]; 

Show[cone, tetrahedron, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
lines = MeshRegion[coordinates, 
  {Line[Append[{4, 5}] @ Subsets[Range[4], {2}]]}, 
  MeshCellStyle -> {0 -> Directive[PointSize[Large], Black],
     {1, _} -> Directive[Blue, Thick],
     {1, 6 | 7} -> Directive[Orange, Thick, Dashed]}, 
  MeshCellLabel -> Table[{0, i} -> labels[[i]], {i, 5}]]; 

 Show[cone, lines, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: I am sorry, I do not understand the numbers in `Line[{{4, 5}, {4, 3}}]` or `{1, 5 | 7} -> Directive[Orange, Thick, Dashed]` Can you explaint them for me?

Comment: @minhthien_2016, the numbers in `Line[{{4, 5}, {4, 3}}]` refer to the part indices of `coordinates`; that is, `4` refers to part 4 of `coordinates` (i.e.,`{0, 0, 0}`) and `3` refers to part 3 of `coordinates` (`{0, 3, 0}`).  The lhs  in `{1, 5 | 7} -> Directive[Orange, Thick, Dashed]` refers to cell indices ( the list `{x,y}` refers to the mesh primitive with dimension `x` (`0` for points, `1` for lines , `2` for faces) and index `y` ). That is,  the rule `{1, 5 | 7} -> Directive[Orange, Thick, Dashed]` says  style the _lines_ with index 5 _or_ 7  using `Directive[Orange, Thick, Dashed]`.

Comment: Thank you very much.